# RxJava Async Nature

Tags: rx-java2

I am learning RxJava. Its all about async.

Here is the code

```
public void a(){
        long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int i = 100000;

        p().map(x -> x*x).subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));

        p().map(x -> x*x).subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));

        long et = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long d = et - st;
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    public Observable<Integer> p(){

        return Observable.create(subsrciber -> {
            for(int i1= 0;i1<10000000;i1++){
                Random r = new Random();
                int g = r.nextInt(100);
                if(i1 == g){
                    //
                }else{
                    //
                }
            }
            subsrciber.onNext(10);
        });

    }
```

What is async in this?
I mean how is the Observable async?

This code seems completely synchronous. I want to make it async. How should I do it?

I mean which part of code runs asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Ankit, Observables are by default to synchronous and executes all its subscribers in order. For your example if you want to see Asynchronous behavior you can try adding a delay to one of the observable like this

p().delay(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(x -> x*x).subscribe(x -> System.out.println(x));

This will make this Observable to execute its subscriber every 3 sec while the other execute without delay

Comment: Ankit Bansal, did you try this? If that worked can you mark my response as answered.